# how to open mysql connection correctly?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Im making a project in C# ASP.NET with MySQL. Im trying to open a MySql connection correctly. Also close/dispose this connection correctly. Becouse it gives That error sometimes

> "mySQL ERROR: system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue
>   was full."

Anyway so I decided to use "using" method my current connection method like that;

```
MySqlConnection baglanti = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlbaglanti"].ToString());

void GirisYap()
{
    using (var cn = baglanti)
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM kullanicilar WHERE kullaniciadi='" + txtKullaniciAdi.Text + "' AND sifre='" + txtSifre.Text + "'"))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader oku = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (oku.Read())
                {
                    Session.Add("AdSoyad", oku["AdSoyad"]);
                    Session.Add("sesid", oku["kullaniciid"]);
                    Response.Redirect("AnaSayfa.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblDurum.Text = "Yanlış Kullanıcı Adı/Şifre !";
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

but its gives an error that "Connection must be valid and open." what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never assign the connection to the Command. Use `new MySqlCommand("sql string...", cn);`. And then refactor to use parameters to avoid sql injection and syntax errors.

Comment: Not sure how many fields that table has but consider replacing that `*` with `adsoyad, kullaniciid` to reduce the number of bytes that get send to you.

Comment: thank you @Crowcoder for ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `using` you should create new `IDisposible` object. When you exit using scope, it will be disposed.

In your code, you generate connection during class object construction. After first usage of `cn`, your `baglanti` object will be disposed. After first usage, you cannot open connection. Hence, you should generate connection object in using statement.

All above is advice, not solution of your problem. Your problem is that, command object does not have connection object. You can pass connectin object to command object via constructor

You should use like:

```
string connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlbaglanti"].ToString());

void GirisYap()
{
    using (var cn = new new MySqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        cn.Open();
        // command object should take connection object
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM kullanicilar WHERE kullaniciadi='" + txtKullaniciAdi.Text + "' AND sifre='" + txtSifre.Text + "'", cn))
        {
            ........
        }
}
```

Comment: well I have to add cn.Open(); anyway. it doesnt work if I dont.

Comment: Yes. After creating `MySqlConnection` object, you should open connection with `cn.Open()`. Then give the connection object to command object.